# How to use a Drive hosted css to customize the receiver?

Tags: css, chromecast

I have published an android Chromecast app. My receiver app is using the default receiver. Now I'm trying to customize the receiver using a css.
I followed the developper guide (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver) and I tried to host this css file on my drive account as it's explained here https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en
But something must be wrong because after having updated my receiver app with the CSS url and restarted my chromecast I don't see any modification. I guess the way I shared the drive hosted css file must be wrong.

Here's my css :

```
.logo {
  background-image: url(logo.png);
}

.progressBar {
  background-color: rgb(244, 132, 45);
}

.watermark {
  background-image: url(watermark.png);
  background-size: 57px 57px;
}
```

both images have also been shared publicly.
BTW looking at Google documentation, it looks like there should be a preview button in the chromecast console, but I don't see it.

Any idea what's going on ?

Comment: On the same page that you enter your CSS for Styled Receiver, there is a Preview button to the right of Save button that will be enabled when you enter a CSS url. Try that and see what the preview says. Also, connect your chrome debugger to port 9222 to see the css in action; that may give you more clues

Comment: As I explained there's no preview button.
I selected Custom style, pasted my url, the app is published and there's no preview button. Samething with a new unpublished app: no preview button. Just the save one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it to work.
The default url when sharing the css file was

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXXXXXXXX/edit?usp=sharing
```

In fact I just needed to change it into

```
https://googledrive.com/host/XXXXXXXXXX
```

To make it work

Then in my css file I had to change both logo.png and watermark.png into absolute url, both hosted on drive in my case so i had to use their shared url (https://googledrive.com/host/yyy)